# Create a summarizing dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table using r. I have a file ordered like this:

[image]

And I would like to use commands to convert it into the following table

[image]

Ill appreciate any help I could get with this. Thanks a lot in advance!

I tried using pivot_wider but the resulting table was not sucessfull